# GWT Editors - MaterialComboBox is assignable to the raw Editor type, but a type parameterization is required

Tags: gwt, gwt-material-design

I'm trying to use the gwt editor framework so that I can have my view (`SingleReplayView`) editing my bean `SingleClaimId`.

Here is my view class:

```java
public class SingleReplayView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<SingleReplayUiHandlers> implements SingleReplayPresenter.MyView, Editor<ReplayClaimId>  
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, SingleReplayView> {
    }

    public interface SingleReplayDriver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<ReplayClaimId, SingleReplayView> {}
    protected static SingleReplayDriver driver = GWT.create(SingleReplayDriver.class);

    @UiField
    MaterialTextBox claimId;

    @UiField
    MaterialComboBox originalEnvironment;

    @UiField
    @Path("replayEnvironment")
    MaterialComboBox replayEnvironment;

    @UiField
    @Path("bmsDisabled")
    MaterialRadioButton bmsDisabled;

    @UiField
    @Path("bmsEnabledWithInjection")
    MaterialRadioButton bmsEnabledWithInjection;

    @UiField
    @Path("bmsEnabledWithNoInjection")
    MaterialRadioButton bmsEnabledWithNoInjection;

    @UiField
    @Path("tariffEnabled")
    MaterialCheckBox tariffEnabled;

    @UiField
    @Path("humDisabled")
    MaterialCheckBox humDisable;

    @Inject
    SingleReplayView(Binder uiBinder) {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
        driver.initialize(this);
    }

    @UiHandler("singleSubmitButton")
    public void submit(ClickEvent event) {
        ReplayClaimId replayClaimId = driver.flush();
        MaterialToast.fireToast(replayClaimId.getClaimId());
    }
}
```

and my bean class

```java
public class ReplayClaimId implements IsSerializable {

    private String claimId;
    private String originalEnvironment;
    private String replayEnvironment;

    private Boolean bmsDisabled;
    private Boolean bmsEnabledWithInjection;
    private Boolean bmsEnabledWithNoInjection;

    private Boolean tariffEnabled;
    private Boolean humDisabled;

    //with setters and getters
}
```

And when I try to compile the code i get error

```
The type gwt.material.design.addins.client.combobox.MaterialComboBox is assignable to the raw Editor type, but a type parameterization is required.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in 'SingleReplayView.java'
```

can please assist?

Comment: Ah sorry I don't know what happened to my first line it like this :    public class SingleReplayView extends ViewWithUiHandlers implements SingleReplayPresenter.MyView, Editor<ReplayClaimId> {

Answer (score 0):

> The type gwt.material.design.addins.client.combobox.MaterialComboBox is assignable to the raw Editor type, but a type parameterization is required.

The error is talking about this (and other similar fields):

```
    @UiField
    MaterialComboBox originalEnvironment;
```

But the generics of the field `MaterialComboBox<T>` show that it must be generic on the type `T` which it is editing. https://gwtmaterialdesign.github.io/gwt-material-demo/apidocs-addins/gwt/material/design/addins/client/combobox/MaterialComboBox.html

In this case, you want T to be the same as it is in your bean type:

```
    private String originalEnvironment;
```

So your `@UiField` should read

```
    @UiField
    MaterialComboBox<String> originalEnvironment;
```

The `replayEnvironment` editor will also need the same parameterization.

Comment: Thanks you so much Colin

Comment: I have solved my issue, it turn out that MaterialComboBox is generic to T as mention by Colin above and It convert that generic in to List so if you put MaterialComboBox<String> your bean property should be List<String> even though the value will be list of size 1 with select value

Comment: In that case, you can write an adaptor editor to wrap the MaterialComboBox, and automatically wrap a single String in a List<String>, and unwrap it again when writing back to the bean. Just implement LeafValueEditor<List<T>>` (or make it `List<String>` for simplicity) and you can have it wrap your combo box each time you need it.